# Python: Cómo importar una función desde un archivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy teniendo problemas para importar una función:

```
   def helloworld():
       print("Hello World!")
```

La tengo en un archivo llamado hello.py dentro de la carpeta: C:/proyectos.

Introduzco lo siguiente:

```
>>> import sys  
>>> sys.path.append('C:/proyectos')
>>> import hello
>>> helloworld()
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
 helloworld()
NameError: name 'helloworld' is not defined
```

No entiendo por qué me da este error si he definido la función helloworld dentro del archivo hello.py
¿Alguien sabe como importar una función que hayas creado dentro de un archivo .py?

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Comment: Recuerda usar `sys.path.append('C:\\Proyectos')`. Desde la consola interactiva usas sys.path, veras que todos los directorios que tienes en referencia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tal como importas el módulo, el espacio de nombres es `hello`, por lo que el acceso correcto es:

```
>>> hello.helloworld()
```

También podría importar todas las referencias del módulo en el espacio de nombres del programa principal con:

```
from hello import *
```

o, mejor aún, importar únicamente la función que te interesa

```
from hello import helloworld
```