# Pasar parámetros a una función en un archivo desde otro en Python

Tags: python, funciones, parámetros

Por mas que lo intento no encuentro la manera de poder pasar unos parámetros a un archivo en python desde otro. Me explico mejor:

**Archivo1.py**

```
def FTP_Conn (srv, usr, pwd):
    ftp = FTP()
    puerto = 21
    ftp.connect(srv, puerto)
    ftp.login(usr, pwd)
    listado = ftp.retrlines("LIST")
```

**Archivo2.py**

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("ruta hacia el archivo1.py"))
from Archivo1.py import FTP_Conn
server = direccion del servidor
user = nombre de usuario
passwd = password
def funcion():
    FTP_Conn(server, user, passwd)
```

*Necesito llamar a la función del archivo1.py desde dentro de otra función en este archivo y pasarle 3 parámetros*

Comentar también que he realizado la importación indicando la ruta con un sys.path.append y he probado importando todo el archivo y solo la función.
La llamada a la función del otro archivo sin parámetros si funciona, pero cuando intento pasarlos, no los recibe y es como si no ejecutase el código.

Llevo muy poquito tiempo en python por lo que cualquier ayuda es bien recibida.

Si me podéis poner un ejemplo os lo agradecería.
Muchas gracias.

He mirado estos 2 hilos pero no resuelven mi duda:

[Acceder a funciones desde otro archivo en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/416227/acceder-a-funciones-desde-otro-archivo-en-python)

[Python: Cómo importar una función desde un archivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38643/python-c%c3%b3mo-importar-una-funci%c3%b3n-desde-un-archivo)

Comment: poné que estás intentando, es muy simple, pero hay que ver donde es tu problema.

Comment: @tincopasan, he editado la pregunta. a ver si se entiende mejor así.

Comment: Si no te ningun error en consola tal vez se deba a que la función si se ejecuta pero no hay ningún return o print

Comment: suponiendo que hayas hecho las importaciones necesarias para que funcione la conexión, ya que no se que biblioteca estás usando, elimina la primera linea: sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("ruta hacia el archivo1.py")) y poné el archivo 1 en el mismo lugar que el archivo 2 para descartar problemas de rutas. La forma de importar y la sintaxis mostrada debería funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Yo soy novato en python... no se si te servira lo que yo haria. Seria lo siguiente:
En archivo2.py pondria esto:

```
from archivo1 import *  (suponiendo que ambos esten en el mismo directorio)
```

y cuando tenga que llamar a la funcion del archivo1 pues haria esto:

```py
FTP_Conn (param1, param2, param3)
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: @Christian, no me da error en consola cierto! Pero si cambio adrede los parámetros de conexión para provocar un error de conexión, tampoco me lo da, si lo ejecuto con debug tampoco me da error. No he probado con la captura de execepciones, pero sospecho que no me dará nada, en fin, que estoy más atascado que una nuez en el culo de una pulga!

Comment: @rgmagritte esta no es mi publicación, si no te da error significa que todo está bien, prueba agregando un `prin("finalizado")` al final de tu función `FTP_Conn()`

Answer (score 0):

#### RESUELTO:

¿Que estaba ocurriendo?

Todo funcionaba correctamente como estaba, pero... un error de novato provocaba el fallo, tan sencillo como que en el archivo2.py al terminar el código de la función, no hice la llamada a la misma. Claramente un despiste gordo.

En cualquier caso **muchas gracias** a todos por vuestro tiempo.

Saludos!